# Which kernel function is triggered when /proc is accessed?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Which function is responsible for main logic of /proc creation?

I have to achieve the behaviour mentioned in this question.
[Is /proc directory generated dynamically per request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33208820/is-proc-directory-generated-dynamically-per-request)

I suppose there is a function that loops through the task list and creates the corresponding entries. I am looking for something like that.

I looked for the functions that uses create_proc_entry() function but i could not find something that stands out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I suppose there is a function that loops through the task list and creates the corresponding entries. I am looking for something like that.

`proc_pid_readdir()` function in `fs/proc/base.c` does exactly that.

That for loop creates all the `/proc/PID` entries. `iter.task` is the current `task_struct` pointer

```
int proc_pid_readdir(struct file *file, struct dir_context *ctx)
{
    /*
     .
     .
     .
      */
    for (iter = next_tgid(ns, iter);
         iter.task;
         iter.tgid += 1, iter = next_tgid(ns, iter)) {
        char name[PROC_NUMBUF];
        int len;

        if (!has_pid_permissions(ns, iter.task, 2))
            continue;

        len = snprintf(name, sizeof(name), "%d", iter.tgid);
        ctx->pos = iter.tgid + TGID_OFFSET;
        if (!proc_fill_cache(file, ctx, name, len,
                     proc_pid_instantiate, iter.task, NULL)) {
            put_task_struct(iter.task);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    ctx->pos = PID_MAX_LIMIT + TGID_OFFSET;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good research! Plus one

Comment: @hek2mgl , starting point you gave me helped a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Actually each module handles it's proc files on it's own. Using Linux' source code you can grep around for the individual file names in proc. This way you should be able find the place of a function of interest.

Comment: Im interested in who creates the process entries like /proc/<pid>. The files in root of /proc is what you are talking about right?

Comment: Indeed grepping for filles in subdirectories is simple than for the /proc/PID entries. They are created deep in the core (I guess). I would grep for something special inside them.. let me check

Comment: Let's use the `/proc/PID/schedstat` file as a starting point for search. Found this in LXR http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/stats.c .. This function creates the information, you could start poking around from here.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Lets see where that will take me to.

Comment: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/proc/base.c Contents of this file looks like relevant. But i couldnt find exactly what i am looking for. Understanding what kernel does is hard.

Comment: Ok i found what i was looking for. Its the `proc_pid_readdir()` function in `fs/proc/base.c` If you edit that in to your answer I can mark it as correct.

Comment: It does not really fit to my answer, also it was your work to find that out. Feel free to post your own answer!