# how to get a pointer to a /proc directory using process id or its corresponding task_struct?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

In my linux experiment(linux kernel version 4.5), I need to create a file in directory /proc/pid in a module. I have got a certain pid and a pointer to its task_struct, but I don't know how to get the pointer to the struct proc_dir_entry of the directory /proc/pid. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Per-process entries in the `/proc` filesystem are created **on the fly** (when requested). For add new per-process files you need to modify existed kernel code. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33319189/3440745) for more info about that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `proc_dir_entry` for process entries under /proc. if you still need to add a directory you need to add an entry to the following data structure in 'fs/proc/base.c'...

```
static const struct pid_entry tgid_base_stuff[];
```

This is where all the virtual `directories` you see under `/proc/pid` are defined. You'd also need to add patch the existing kernel to make sure you handle the new entry.